# How to refresh page so my table does not keep getting added to existing table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Whenever I click on my button to fire the below query it keeps on appending to the existing table.Is there any way I can refresh the page for every button click.

```
function submitClick() {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    const rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Orders/");
    const query = rootRef.orderByChild('Session').equalTo('VEG');
    query.on("child_added", snap => {
      var user_id = snap.child("User id").val();
      var name = snap.child("Username").val().toUpperCase();
      $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + user_id + "</td> <td>" + name + "</td> <td>" + email +
        "</td><td>" + address + "</td><td>" + dabba_type + "</td><td>" + session + "</td><td>" + start +
        "</td><td>" + end + "</td><td>" + phone + "</td><td>" + "Rs " + price + "</td><td>" + feedback + "</td></tr>");
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: use `.html()` instead of `.append()`.

Comment: Do you want to refresh the page or the table itself?
If the page, use `location.refresh`

Answer (score 1):

try adding `$("#table_body").empty()` at the start of the function

Answer (score 1):

create the html into variable and then add to the body

```
var html = "<tr><td>" + user_id + "</td> <td>" + name + "</td> <td>" + email +
"</td><td>" + address + "</td><td>" + dabba_type + "</td><td>" + session + "  </td><td>" + start +
"</td><td>" + end + "</td><td>" + phone + "</td><td>" + "Rs " + price + "</td><td>" + feedback + "</td></tr>";

$("#table_body").html(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand. You can use ajax to reload page or `datatables` be the best way for refreshing table with out page reload. If you want just reload page then use

```
 location.reload();
```